# Correct way to turn on and check for a runtime flag that's only changed once

Tags: c, multithreading, performance, optimization

In C (especialy when working with microcontrollers), I've encountered situations where I start a thread that waits for some initial flag to be set. For the sake of this example, let's just say that I have a thread that only can truly start once some specific packet has been received. **Once the flag is said, it will never be unset!** The way I handle would be like this:

```
int receive_flag = 0;
void thread() 
{
  while (1)
  {
     usleep(SOME_CONSTANT_DELAY);
     if (!receive_flag)
       continue;
     else
       // this code should always run after some init happens
  }
}
```

And then maybe in my generic packet receiver (different source file), I'd have something like

```
void process_packet(const byte p[])
{
  // imagine that I have checks to see if
  // packet is valid (size > 0, certain format, blabla)
  if (p[0] == 0xFF) // maybe the first instance of this header
  // will trigger the above thread to actually do stuff
    settheflag();  // imagine I have a settheflag API exposed that changes
    // receive_flag to 1
  else
    // do other stuff
}
```

Because my question is about the style/optimizations, I intentionally made the code incomplete (perhaps I should have done psuedo-code, but oh well), but I hope you guys get the idea. Assume that the rest of the code around it are correct, and I do not care if the thread starts a couple of iterations too late (so I don't care about any async issues).

Is this the right way to approach this situation? My concerns are:

- In the looping thread, is the if(!receive_flag) going to cause extra performance concerns? Esp. because receive_flag should never be 0 AFTER it gets set once.
- In the packet handler, is it better to check if the flag is set BEFORE setting the flag or just always set the flag (this is regarding performance, I know both would work... It's a matter of is it better to write once and always read after OR always write)

If there is an outright better way to handle this, that'll also be appreciated!

This also might be OS dependent... If so, I'm for now concerned with eLinux. If it needs to be more specific (with processor and stuff), let's just say this is for Raspberry pi 2A: 900MHz quad-core ARM Cortex-A7 CPU on the latest Raspian OS. If you want, you are free to use other architectures, but please try to keep it in the context of embedded systems.

I'll also be appreciative of C++ (up to C++11) solutions, but I'd prefer just C solutions.

EDIT:
For clarification, I cannot start the thread from the process_packet function for code organization purposes.

Comment: Most likely you could use a [`std::condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) in C++.

Comment: Seems fine to me as long as you are sure that the first thread will "see" the variable being set. This isn't always the case as those details are undefined in the standard. You might need to make the int `volatile` or even use a concurrency tool like a semaphore

Comment: "Once the flag is said, it will never ben unset" if thats the case, then why dont you simply start the thread only when its supposed to do something (instead of starting it in a sleep mode and then having to wake it up) ?

Comment: If you are insane enough, you could try messing with self-modifying code. Emphasis on **insane**.

Comment: you can avoid your "usleep(SOME_CONSTANT_DELAY);" with a semaphore or mutex and let the os deal with the "lock"

Comment: @tobi303 .  for code organization purposes. If I have a board that runs a number of threads, it makes the code much cleaner if I can just start all the threads at runtime. Also because this check only needs to happen in a specific flavor of the build.

Comment: @BenSteffan     I've seen that done in mic1 before... I don't think I'm that insane! But that is definitely a possible solution. Unfortunately (as far as I know) not portable and really hacky

Comment: That code is broken by design. Read about the abstract machine and observable behaviour. Also busy-polling in all threads instead of correct synchronisation mechanisms is a very bad idea. Especially in embedded systems where EMI and power consumption are typically relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two related issues: structure (which you asked about) and consistency (which you didn't, but still needs addressing).

---

**Structure**

in reverse order of preference (last is best) because it just works better this way™:

- better: restructure your loop so you don't keep checking something that can't change back:

  ```
  void thread() {
    // wait until we're ready
    while (!receive_flag) {
       usleep(SOME_CONSTANT_DELAY);
    }
    // init steady state here
    // then enter steady state loop
    while (1) {
       // your code here
    }
  }
  ```
- better still: use proper synchronization rather than busy-waiting

  ```
  void thread() {
    // wait until we're ready
    {
       std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(flag_mutex);
       while (!receive_flag) {
           flag_condvar.wait(lock);
       }
    }
    // init steady state here ...
  ```
- even better: if you have *"... a `settheflag` API exposed ..."*, you can add a matching `waitfortheflag()` function you call *once* at the start of your thread function. Just move the initial wait loop into that.
- best: don't start the thread before you're ready for it to run.

  Ideally move the thread start inside your existing `settheflag` API function.

  There may be good reasons to avoid starting a thread from your packet handler, eg. if it's expensive, but this is the cleanest way when possible.

---

**Consistency:** your use of a plain `int` for the flag is not portable!

It *may* work on your platform (I have no idea, so will defer to you), but a different compiler (or a future update to your current compiler) can legally hoist the load of `receive_flag` out of the loop and only do it once, which will break everything pretty dramatically.

Solutions are, in order of preference (first is best, for reflective symmetry):

1. proper synchronization (`std::mutex` etc. or `pthread_mutex_*` for C)
2. make your flag a `std::atomic` (C++ only, but exactly correct and portable)
3. rely on your something platform-specific which is actually documented (compiler intrinsics, like GCC's `__atomic_load` for example)
4. make your flag `volatile` and relying on your platform do what you hope it will and not just what the language spec requires (this is essentially a compiler extension which is *not* explicitly documenting the desired behaviour)
5. rely on your existing platform just doing (and continuing to do, forever) the right thing

Comment: I'd bold or do something to make the Best option stand out more. Casual reader's probably going to implement the first option because it's first and  has the most code. I know you can't help the truly stupid, but it's nice to try.

Comment: @user4581301 the best option forces a restructure of the program. More like best IF it's doable, and first option is pure C and not platform specific.

Comment: "you should probably …" - NO! You have to use atomics! On small systems, `volatile might be sufficient, but that has to be verified with the compiler documentation and datasheet.

Comment: @C.Sano I see where you're coming from on avoiding the mass re-write, but if you have threads there's nothing that forces the best option to not be pure C. You simply don't call the thread creating routine until needed. Option two may be available and option three can be inserted in your current current code with minimal fuss,no architectural earthquake, and less coupling.

Comment: @C.Sano you can implement all versions with C instead, I just used C++ for the example code because it's less verbose. You just need `pthread_mutex_t` instead of `std::mutex`, manual `pthread_mutex_lock`/`_unlock` instead of `std::unique_lock`, etc. etc.

Comment: @Olaf true, it's terrible advice in general. I assumed OP knows the specific platform well enough that the original code _works_, although it obviously isn't portable. If that's the case, then `volatile` adds nothing. If it's not the case, going straight to `std::atomic` is better (for C++).

Comment: @Useless: Without `volatile` (atomics have to be `volatile`, too), any modern compiler will generate unwanted code, possibly even without optimisations enabled (gcc applies some optimisations even with `-O0`).

Comment: Well the main idea behind adding this check is for debug purposes. The connections are done serially and the way the boards are powered up, the check for the thread is not necessary (it can immediately run) for the release. However, it really helps with debugging behavior to have a way to send custom packets, and we do that with tcp connections instead of serial and also connect at run time. If that makes any sense. And @Useless thanks for the clarification for the pthread I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sleeping for some set amount of time and checking a variable, why don't you use a std::condition_variable or a pthread_cond_t. These are condition variables which you can read about [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)). You can use these to wait and unwait threads from anywhere in your program. Here's an example of your code above but using condition variables instead of bools.

```
std::condition_variable cv; //Create a CV
std::mutex lock; //Create a lock
void thread(){
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ulock(lock); 
        cv.wait(ulock); //Wait this thread until it is awoken
        //your code here
}
void process_packet(const byte p[]){
        if(p[0] == 0xFF)
                cv.notify_all(); //wake up all CVs 
        else
                //other stuff
}
```

Comment: You either need the loop or the optional predicate argument to deal with spurious wakeups - this code is potentially buggy as currently written.

Comment: @Useless True, but this is simply trying to the use of these variables, not implement OPs function for him.